# How to reproduce the same scrolling effect?

Tags: javascript, css

I found an awesome website with gorgeous scrolling effect.
http://bonhommeparis.com/

I tried to do the same but i did not find how to have the same effect.
Is there anyone who know how to perform that ?

Comment: Look up parellex scrolling

Comment: I know how to do parallax scrolling but this one has a special transition effect and i can't figure how to do it

Comment: hmmm, sure looks like parellex too me, with an on onload() am I missing something?

Comment: [this question is off-topic (#3)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @APH i tried to add something like "transition : transform 2s ease-out" on the element but its not that great.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for parallax scrolling effects.  [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) is an easy to use js library.  For some examples of what you can do see http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/ has some great tutorials on how to get started

Good luck!

Comment: Try to inspect element and check the css of "<section id="background">" look at the property "transform: translate3d( ) " while scrolling. This is what im trying to do